# Rake searchkick reindex not working in heroku search box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, searchkick, search-box

I unable reindex in heroku once i deploy my code to heroku server with running **heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Listing**, i did do **heroku run rake db:migrate**

```
rake aborted!
Faraday::TimeoutError: Net::ReadTimeout
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:82:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:40:in `block in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:87:in `with_net_http_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:32:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-1.3.0/lib/searchkick/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:21:in `block in perform_request'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you have elastic search installed and running

Comment: Is solve, due to tehy upgrade to newer version bug. Thanks